# Can't boot into arch after changing motherboard and CPU

Tags: arch-linux, boot

I changed my motherboard from an MSI Z97 PC Mate to an ASUS Aurous BM450 ELITE and my CPU from an Intel i5 4590k to an AMD Ryzen 5 3600X, and I haven't been able to boot into my arch linux drive since.

The BIOS boot menu lists my two SSDs (one has arch installed and the other has Windows) and Windows Boot Manager. I was able to boot into Windows, which displayed "Getting devices ready" and is perfectly usable but booting into the SSD with my arch installation just shows a flickering cursor that changes position and then goes back to the boot menu.

I have tried chrooting into the drive with a live USB and running `grub-mkconfig > /boot/grub/grub` and `mkinitcpio -p linux` but to no avail.

What could the problem be and how could I fix it? Other answers on here say that the kernel prints some useful message before rebooting but mine only shows a flickering cursor.

Answer (score -1):

I needed to reinstall grub to my EFI partition and reinstall linux to my /boot directory. [This forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=229623) helped.